# Crash when Database.Migrate() is called during startup

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core

I have a Xamarin Forms application which uses Entity Framework Core. When I start and test on the emulator everything is fine. Also when I start on a device which has a previous version running it works as expected. But when I run the app on a device with no data on it crashes when the following is executed:

```
        var context = new EfCoreContext();
        context.Database.Migrate();
```

I first noticed it when the prelaunch reports of google failed on 7 of 9 devices. The error there is:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/walleye/walleye:9/PQ2A.190405.003/5310204:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 12770, tid: 12770, name: utions.moneyfox  >>> com.applysolutions.moneyfox <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000007fec923bd0
    x4  0000007f29ade9a0  x5  0000007fec923c60  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000000
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000000  x14 00000000ffffffff  x15 0000000000000000
    x16 0000007f1bd1d1f8  x17 0000007f1bb44670  x18 0000000000000008  x19 0000007f1bd34560
    x20 0000000000000002  x21 0000000000000000  x22 0000000000000000  x23 000000000000007f
    x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000007fec923d50  x27 0000007f16bdda34
    x28 0000007f29ade000  x29 0000007fec923070
    sp  0000007fec923070  lr  0000007f1ba8b658  pc  0000007f1bb44678
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000177678  /data/app/com.applysolutions.moneyfox-tqWhOmZmoDQ8yd5YLjvTqg==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_jit_info_get_method+8)
```

Funny enough, when I remove the Migrate call, start and add it again the app can start. Also in the prelaunch report are always 2 or 3 devices who can start the app without any issue. I can imagine that this is some kind of timing issue or that some other effect play in here. But the crash is consistently on that call no matter where in my application I put it.

I tried to get more information with try catches and global error handler which should log to my log file. But unfortunately, nothing is caught.
Is there a way to narrow down the issue, may be based on the error log from the prelaunch report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems that is an issue in Xamarin.Android: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/580820/xamarin-problem-following-update-to-vs2019-161.html

And it seems like it is fixed with 16.1.4.